# Add class based on div content with javascript

Tags: javascript

These are the 8 cards player1 has at the beginning of my card game.

```
<div class="player1HandCard1 player1Hand">7♦</div>
<div class="player1HandCard2 player1Hand">2♦</div>
<div class="player1HandCard3 player1Hand">A♣</div>
<div class="player1HandCard4 player1Hand">A♠</div>
<div class="player1HandCard5 player1Hand">8♦</div>
<div class="player1HandCard6 player1Hand">10♥</div>
<div class="player1HandCard7 player1Hand">9♣</div>
<div class="player1HandCard8 player1Hand">9♠</div>
```

Using javascript, I would like to add a .red class to just the div's who have the ♦ and the ♥ suits in their content.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: What did you try? What error did you get?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. We're not a free coding service.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
const divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
   if(divs[i].innerHTML.includes("♦") || divs[i].innerHTML.includes("♥")) {
       divs[i].classList.add("red");
   }
}
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="player1HandCard2 player1Hand">7♦</div>
<div class="player1HandCard4 player1Hand">2♦</div>
<div class="player1HandCard3 player1Hand">A♣</div>
<div class="player1HandCard1 player1Hand">A♠</div>
<div class="player1HandCard5 player1Hand">8♦</div>
<div class="player1HandCard6 player1Hand">10♥</div>
<div class="player1HandCard7 player1Hand">9♣</div>
<div class="player1HandCard8 player1Hand">9♠</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what I tried to do but without good results!

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('div')] // get all the divs
  .filter(d=>['♦', '♥'] // filter to only those
    .some(c=>d.textContent.includes(c)) // where either '♦' or '♥' occurs in the text
  )
  .forEach(c=>c.classList.add('red')); // for each of those filtered divs, add the class .red
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="player1HandCard2 player1Hand">7♦</div>
<div class="player1HandCard4 player1Hand">2♦</div>
<div class="player1HandCard3 player1Hand">A♣</div>
<div class="player1HandCard1 player1Hand">A♠</div>
<div class="player1HandCard5 player1Hand">8♦</div>
<div class="player1HandCard6 player1Hand">10♥</div>
<div class="player1HandCard7 player1Hand">9♣</div>
<div class="player1HandCard8 player1Hand">9♠</div>
```

An even shorter version makes use of `el.classList.toggle(className, bool)`:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('div')] // get all the divs
  .forEach( // for each of those divs
    c=>c.classList.toggle( // toggle the class .red based on the condition
      'red', 
      ['♦', '♥'].some(s=>c.textContent.includes(s))
    )
  );
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="player1HandCard2 player1Hand">7♦</div>
<div class="player1HandCard4 player1Hand">2♦</div>
<div class="player1HandCard3 player1Hand">A♣</div>
<div class="player1HandCard1 player1Hand">A♠</div>
<div class="player1HandCard5 player1Hand">8♦</div>
<div class="player1HandCard6 player1Hand">10♥</div>
<div class="player1HandCard7 player1Hand">9♣</div>
<div class="player1HandCard8 player1Hand">9♠</div>
```